# NestJS Postgres Typeorm database migration

Tags: node.js, typescript, postgresql, nestjs, typeorm

I have a NestJS API with TypeORM entities with Postgres DB.
What I am trying to do is to set up some initial migration and then to have as series of migrations as the project proceeds.
The migration command in package.json is not working. Any help is appreciated.

Here are the errors:

```
yarn typeorm:cli                                                               
yarn run v1.22.18
$ ts-node -r tsconfig-paths/register ./node_modules/typeorm/cli -f src/typeorm/factory/typeorm-migrations.config.ts
Usage: cli <command> [options]

Commands:
  cli schema:sync                Synchronizes your entities with database
                                 schema. It runs schema update queries on all
                                 connections you have. To run update queries on
                                 a concrete connection use -c option.
  cli schema:log                 Shows sql to be executed by schema:sync
                                 command. It shows sql log only for your default
                                 dataSource. To run update queries on a concrete
                                 connection use -c option.
  cli schema:drop                Drops all tables in the database on your
                                 default dataSource. To drop table of a concrete
                                 connection's database use -c option.
  cli query [query]              Executes given SQL query on a default
                                 dataSource. Specify connection name to run
                                 query on a specific dataSource.
  cli entity:create <path>       Generates a new entity.
  cli subscriber:create <path>   Generates a new subscriber.
  cli migration:create <path>    Creates a new migration file.
  cli migration:generate <path>  Generates a new migration file with sql needs
                                 to be executed to update schema.
  cli migration:run              Runs all pending migrations.
  cli migration:show             Show all migrations and whether they have been
                                 run or not
  cli migration:revert           Reverts last executed migration.
  cli version                    Prints TypeORM version this project uses.
  cli cache:clear                Clears all data stored in query runner cache.
  cli init                       Generates initial TypeORM project structure. If
                                 name specified then creates files inside
                                 directory called as name. If its not specified
                                 then creates files inside current directory.

Options:
  -h, --help     Show help                                             [boolean]
  -v, --version  Show version number                                   [boolean]

Not enough non-option arguments: got 0, need at least 1
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

```
npm run  migration:generate BaseMigration                                           

> npm run typeorm:cli -- migration:generate -n "BaseMigration"

> ts-node -r tsconfig-paths/register ./node_modules/typeorm/cli -f src/typeorm/factory/typeorm-migrations.config.ts "migration:generate" "-n" "BaseMigration"

cli migration:generate <path>

Generates a new migration file with sql needs to be executed to update schema.

Options:
  -h, --help          Show help                                        [boolean]
  -d, --dataSource    Path to the file where your DataSource instance is
                      defined.                               [string] [required]
  -p, --pretty        Pretty-print generated SQL      [boolean] [default: false]
  -o, --outputJs      Generate a migration file on Javascript instead of
                      Typescript                      [boolean] [default: false]
      --dr, --dryrun  Prints out the contents of the migration instead of
                      writing it to a file            [boolean] [default: false]
      --ch, --check   Verifies that the current database is up to date and that
                      no migrations are needed. Otherwise exits with code 1.
                                                      [boolean] [default: false]
  -t, --timestamp     Custom timestamp for the migration name
                                                       [number] [default: false]
  -v, --version       Show version number                              [boolean]

Not enough non-option arguments: got 0, need at least 1
```

`package.json`

```
   "typeorm:cli": "ts-node -r tsconfig-paths/register ./node_modules/typeorm/cli -f src/typeorm/factory/typeorm-migrations.config.ts",
   "migration:generate": "npm run typeorm:cli -- migration:generate -n"
```

Here are my config files:

`typeorm.config.ts`

```
import { TypeOrmModuleOptions } from "@nestjs/typeorm";

export const typeOrmBaseConfig: TypeOrmModuleOptions = {
  type: 'postgres',
  synchronize: false,
  logging: true,
  entities: ['src/typeorm/entities/**/*.ts'],
  migrations: ['src/typeorm/migrations/**/*.ts'],
  subscribers: ['src/typeorm/subscribers/**/*.ts'],
};
```

`typeorm-migration.config.ts`

```
import { typeOrmBaseConfig } from './typeorm.config';

const migrationConfig = {
  ...typeOrmBaseConfig,
  cli: {
    entitiesDir: 'src/typeorm/entities',
    migrationsDir: 'src/typeorm/migrations',
    subscribersDir: 'src/typeorm/subscribers'
  },
  host: process.env.DATABASE_HOST,
  port: parseInt(process.env.DATABASE_PORT || '3306', 10),
  username: process.env.DATABASE_USERNAME,
  database: process.env.DATABASE_NAME,
  password: process.env.DATABASE_PASSWORD,
};

export = migrationConfig;
```

`typeorm-connection.factory.ts`

```
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { ConfigService } from '@nestjs/config';
import { TypeOrmModuleOptions, TypeOrmOptionsFactory } from '@nestjs/typeorm';
import { PostgresConnectionOptions } from 'typeorm/driver/postgres/PostgresConnectionOptions';

import { AwsSecretsFactory } from 'src/aws/aws.secrets.factory';
import { ConfigOptions } from 'src/config/configuration';

import { typeOrmBaseConfig } from './typeorm.config';

@Injectable()
export class TypeOrmConnectionsFactory implements TypeOrmOptionsFactory {
  private readonly awsFactory: AwsSecretsFactory;

  constructor(private readonly configService: ConfigService) {
    this.awsFactory = new AwsSecretsFactory(configService);
  }

  async createTypeOrmOptions(): Promise<TypeOrmModuleOptions> {
    const secret = await this.awsFactory.getSecret();
    return {
      ...typeOrmBaseConfig,
      host: this.configService.get(ConfigOptions.DatabaseHost) || secret.host,
      port: secret.port,
      username: secret.username,
      password: secret.password,
      database: this.configService.get(ConfigOptions.DatabaseName),
      ssl: this.configService.get(ConfigOptions.DatabaseSecureConnect),
    } as PostgresConnectionOptions;
  }
}
```

and in `app.module.ts`

```
...
@Module({
  imports: [
    ConfigModule.forRoot({
      load: [configuration],
    }),
    TypeOrmModule.forRootAsync({
      useClass: TypeOrmConnectionsFactory,
      inject: [],
      imports: [ConfigModule],
    }),
...
```

My initial hunch is that the configuration from js files are not kicking in as well as from the command line are ignored.
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The latest version on typeorm has removed these capabilities. So had to downgrade the version of typeorm.